# What will be the value of 'rs' if the following code worked?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

```
preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("select * from mark where clsnum='"+t1.getText()+"'");
rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(); // ResultSet
```

Suppose the above SQL query worked, that is it found values corresponding to the searched 'clsnum'. Then what will be the value of 'rs' ?

Comment: hint, the code should be `ResultSet rs = ....`

Comment: @brian It was declared in my code earlier.

Comment: So are you asking what a [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) is?

Comment: @brian Am not asking what a ResultSet is. Am asking what will  be the value stored in 'rs' when the SQL query is executed.

Comment: That depends on what's in the database.  It will contain every row from mark with a clsnum equal to your text.

Comment: @brian ok..thanks. What will be the value of 'rs' if the query found no row ?

Comment: An empty [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()) never null.

Comment: @brian Now, suppose I need to display a message depending upon the value in 'rs'. If 'rs' contains a row I need to display a message 'Number Found'. If 'rs' contains no value I need to display a message 'Number Not Found'. So how can I do it ? [if(rs==??)]

Comment: @Tom: Do you want to check if a value exists or not based on a condition?

Answer (score 1):

> *suppose I need to display a message depending upon the value in `'rs'`. If `'rs'` contains a row I need to display a message `'Number Found'`. If `'rs'` contains no value I need to display a message `'Number Not Found'`. So how can I do it ?*

**Example 1**:

```
SELECT COUNT( clsnum ) AS match_count FROM MARK WHERE clsnum ?
```

If `match_count` is grater than `0`, then show message `'Number Found'` else `'Number Not Found'`.

**Example 2**:

```
SELECT COUNT( clsnum ) > 0 AS match_found FROM MARK WHERE clsnum ?
```

If `match_found` is `true`, then show message `'Number Found'` else `'Number Not Found'`.

**Example 3**:

```
SELECT IF( COUNT( clsnum ) > 0,
           'Number Found', 
           'Number Not Found' 
       ) AS message_to_display
FROM MARK 
WHERE clsnum ?
```

If your requirement is just to display the message, read the `message_to_display` from `ResultSet` and display.

And, you are not using prepared statement as it should be. Use place holders for input values and bind them using relevant `setXXX` method.

**Example 4**:

```
String query = "
    SELECT IF( COUNT( clsnum ) > 0,
               'Number Found', 
               'Number Not Found' 
           ) AS message_to_display
    FROM MARK 
    WHERE clsnum ?";

PreparedStatement pst = connect.prepareStatement( query );
pst.setString( 1, t1.getText() );

ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
String messageToDisplay = "Number Not Found";
if( rs.next() ) {
  messageToDisplay  = rs.getString( message_to_display );
}
// procedure further with your other operations
```

Comment: Since am not much experienced with MySQL, it will take me time to understand this examples. Anyway thanks for your help.